# Is there a way to use the FitNesse / SLIM engine to launch test suites designed with FitPro (,suite + .fit web pages)?

Tags: java, integration-testing, fitnesse

My company is using FitPro + FitLibrary to test our applications. Our main test suites are .suite files and they invoke FIT tests pages, which bear the .fit extension (contents 
is HTML).

Our application Fixtures are built on top of FitLibraryRunner.jar (a release issued on 01/28/2007), and we have a .bat/.sh script which launches our FIT tests suite using
com.luxoft.fitpro.runner.TestCaseRunner, which is part of the fitpro.jar library.
This setup is convenient for us because we provide the same application but customized for many customers, and all you need to run FIT tests is fitpro.jar among your classpath, and you don't depending upon other stuff.

As FitPro seems to be no longer maintained, our alternative would be to switch to FitNesse.

Now, it would seem as per my understanding that FitNesse does not offer runners that would allow executing FIT tests suites outside of its wiki. Let me precise that the usage of a Wiki is not really useful for us due to us packaging the same libraries but in differents stages of development, and to many customers.

I would like to know if any of you could ever succeeded in launching the FitNesse/SLIM engine outside of the wiki context ? I am looking for a way to invoke a Runner provided with FitNesse, that reads a main suite test file (.suite) and produces an HTML or XML-based report as output, just like the way we do with FitPro.

I am also told that I could not use the .suite and .fit pages we have created with FitPro over the years.

Thanks in advance for any feedback!
J-C

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the FitNesse wiki, then FitNesse doesn't add any value for you.  FitNesse renders HTML from its wiki pages and passes them to a test execution engine, like Slim, FitLibrary, fitSharp, etc.  FitLibrary and fitSharp can also execute tests sourced from HTML files.  I haven't used FitPro but it appears to feed FitLibrary with tests from its own .suite and .fit files.  Your best bet may be to use FitLibrary's FolderRunner and organize your suites into folders of HTML files that FolderRunner can process.